# How should I turn my numpy array into a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am reading in images and trying to process them. I have read them into a numpy array with the dimensions 407, 372, 312 that I want to turn into an array with dimensions 407, 372 * 312, or basically have each row of the array being the information of each 372 * 312 image. I have tried flatten but that is just returning an 1D array with all the info in one line.

Comment: first using what lib or method of processing it? then  you find  a best way  to but them in 2d,  Secondly why the third dimension is so big (312)

Comment: `flattened_images = images.reshape((len(images), -1))`